# Android M API 23 error to load lib .so files

Tags: android, android-studio, shared-libraries, android-6.0-marshmallow, aac

hello guys i have aac decoder in my app

it was working great when i was on API level 22 ..

but when i was using API level 23 .. my app goes crash and gives me an error unable to lib files

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
```

i was search lots of pages but nothing helping found .. 
problem was only on latest version of android .. app was working great in older version of android ..

here is my libs

```
aacdecoder-android-libs-0.8.zip
```

|---src
     |---main
           |---jniLibs

```
              > aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar
                > armeabi
                   > libaacdecoder.so
              > armeabi-v7a
                   > libaacdecoder.so
              > mips
                  > libaacdecoder.so
              > x86
                > libaacdecoder.so
```

how i can load libs in latest version of android M

i also tried

```
 System.loadLibrary("src/main/amn/armeabi/libaacdecoder.so");
        System.loadLibrary("src/main/amn/armeabi-v7a/libaacdecoder.so");
        System.loadLibrary("src/main/amn/mips/libaacdecoder.so");
        System.loadLibrary("src/main/amn/x86/libaacdecoder.so");
        System.loadLibrary("src/main/amn/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar");
```

but nothings works :(

thank you in advance .. m waiting

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue !!!

Comment: nope no sol here ..i was using alternative method :)

Comment: any update on this? I was just trying to use it to api 24 and it still fails with same problem.

Comment: @AmeeT what is the alternative method? i really need to make my app work

Comment: Guys i find alternative method .. Try EXOPlayer working greats :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem for api 26 So:

1- you need to implments this new library  :
      https://github.com/hichemcesar24/AACDecoder

2- you need to change in gradle  I am using below this code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.8"
    group = 'com.spoledge.aacdecoder'
    version = '0.8-SNAPSHOT'
    ndk { stl "gnustl_static" }
}

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = []
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
   // def ndkDir =plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
   def ndkDir = project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath


    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd", '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build", '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
}
```

3- change classpath of build gradle to :

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

4- if have problem in gradle So you need to delete :

```
 def ndkDir = project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath
```

and changed with this:

```
 def ndkDir =plugins.getPlugin('com.android.library').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
```